# Why app.default_url_options shows example.com in my rails3.0.9 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Its weird that when I do `app.default_url_options` in my production env console `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`, it shows `example.com`

In `production.rb` file, I've set the:
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.com' }

All of my apps urls are rendering as `example.com` in production environment.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c 
Loading production environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > app.root_url
 => "http://www.example.com/"

> app.default_url_options
=> {:host=>"www.example.com", :protocol=>"http"}

> ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
 => {:host=>"etxpress.com"}

> ActionController::Base.default_url_options
=> {}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried searching your files for the string "example.com"?

Comment: In the rails app console, its the desired behavior of showing example.com as the root_url unless you pass `:host => any.com`. Well, the problem was with my YAML and rubygems error not playing nicely. http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/4300